# Restrict direct file access with Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache

How can I restrict direct access to every file that has .inc. in the file name? Basically I did that to point out that the specific file must only be included. Already using Apache and mod_rewrite for basic SEO purposes, by this goes a "bit" beyond my knowledge. .htaccess should somehow do the trick straight away, hopefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.inc\. [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

or this works too

```
RewriteRule \.inc\. - [F]
```

This will give a permission denied.

Or you can also use a 404 page not found:

```
RewriteRule \.inc\. /404.php [L,NC] #or your own 404 page file
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Life saver!