# Avoid copy source code / Access with PHP

Tags: php, css

I have a CSS File, for example how can I avoid the direct access to it?

As example I have the file

**index.php**

```
    <?php  @$access == "ok"; ?>
    <link href="/fonts/test.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**test.php**

```
    header("Content-type: text/css", true);
    if($access == "ok"){
    echo 'body{color:red;}';
    }
```

You have an idea how to do this idea?

Comment: It may be wiser to restrict direct access to .css files using .htacess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict direct file access with Apache .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321369/restrict-direct-file-access-with-apache-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it like that:

index.php

```
    <?php $_SESSION["ok"] = "ok"; ?>
    <link href="/test.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

test.php

```
    session_start();
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Content-type: text/css", true);
    if(isset($_SESSION["ok"])){
    echo 'body{color:red;}';
    }
    session_destroy();
```

But problem is the page (test.php) needs to get refreshed again to get "blank" so i added to the Header the expiring but it didnt worked!

Comment: header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Connection: close");
    header("Content-type: text/css", true);

Comment: As other said you can easily do this via the .htaccess file.